# HTML to jade conversion

Tags: node.js, pug

How to translate the below html into jade

```
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" class="{@ .CSS @}">
```

htm2jade gave

```
#app.{@..CSS.@}(ng-app='myApp')
```

bur jade rendered it as

```
 <div id="app">.{@..CSS.@}(ng-app='myApp')
```

how can i represent the first line of html as jade.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-identifier class names can be included in the attributes:

```
#app(class='{@ .CSS @}', ng-app='myApp')
```

They'll be combined with any "*selector*" names:

```
#app.foo-bar(class='{@ .CSS @}', ng-app='myApp')
```

```
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" class="foo-bar {@ .CSS @}"></div>
```